# Attach a file to a draft in Gmail using IMAP using GO

Tags: go, gmail, imap, attachment

I managed to create a script that creates an email draft using Gmail in GO. I would like a solution to be able to attach a file to this draft.

p.s.: It needs to be a draft because someone else will review the email before sending it.
The code is here:

```
package main
    
    import (
        "bytes"
        "log"
        "os"
        "time"
    
        "github.com/emersion/go-imap"
        "github.com/emersion/go-imap/client"
    )
    
    func main() {
        log.Println("Connecting to server...")
    
        // Connect to server
        c, err := client.DialTLS(os.Getenv("IMAP_SERVER"), nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Println("Connected")
    
        // Don't forget to logout
        defer c.Logout()
    
        // Login
        if err := c.Login(os.Getenv("IMAP_USER"), os.Getenv("IMAP_PASSWORD")); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Println("Logged in")
    
        // Write the message to a buffer
        var b bytes.Buffer
        b.WriteString("From: <...@gmail.com>\r\n")
        b.WriteString("To: <...@gmail.com>\r\n")
        b.WriteString("Subject: Append test\r\n")
        b.WriteString("\r\n")
        // Message body
        b.WriteString("Append test using Gmail IMAP and Draft folder")
    
        // Append it to Drafts
        if err := c.Append("[Gmail]/Drafts", nil, time.Now(), &b); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
```

Comment: Did you look for MIME serialization libraries?

Comment: Yes, but it was not too helpful, i cannot find the solution yet.